# Xcode 12.0 - XCFrameworks not working in test target

Tags: swift, xcode, rx-swift, xctest, xcframework

I have a problem with Xcode 12.0. I'm trying to make a switch to XCFrameworks using Carthage `--use-xcframeworks`. Carthage build is a success, I can switch fat libraries to XCFrameworks and make App targets build and run. The problem is with testing. When I'm adding Quick, RxTesting, or RxBlocking to test targets it doesn't build, Xcode doesn't see symbols.
I have found a problem on RxSwift git: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/2292
Maybe someone made it work and successfully switched to XCFrameworks.

Comment: Looks like [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66344749/admob-framework-class-not-detected-by-xcode-interface-builder/66457263#66457263) are having issues as well if they support < iOS 13 and use the ObjC runtime